# Link-local (zeroconf) networking with multiple hosts/interfaces

Tags: networking

I have a machine (hostname `foo`) with two wired network interfaces, eth0 and eth1.  When I connect another host `bar` to one of them (eth0), I can see in either one's NetworkManager that it's using "Link-Local Only" mode:

[image]

This works great—I can instantly communicate between the two hosts just with `ping foo.local` or `ping bar.local`.

However, as soon as I plug in a second host onto eth1, `foo.local` and `bar.local` become unreachable to each other, due to now having multiple overlapping 169.254.0.0/16 routes.  How do I fix this **permanently**, such that I don't need to repeat some `ip` incantations on each host every time I connect a host, and **also minimize the amount of static IP configuration I have to do** (I'd like to solve this in the most [ZeroConfNetworking](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZeroConfNetworking)-ish way possible)?

Answer (score 0):

It a shot in the dark, but could you try this on the host `foo`:

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```